# Jython SyntaxError: Unknown encoding: pythonql

Tags: python, python-3.x, jython, jython-2.7

when i run below python file as python .it throws no error

```
  #coding: pythonql

 print([ select y for x in [1,2,3] let y = x**2 ])
```

**but when i run with jython it throws following error**

> File "src/firstex.py", line 1
>
> SyntaxError: Unknown encoding: pythonql

why? please help....
**im using python 3.3 and jython 2.7**

Answer (score 0):

you have written a pythonql query, but apparently you haven't installed pythonql. Check the docs at www.pythonql.org

Comment: i have pythonql module . when i run above code as python its running good, but when i run with jython it throws error. does jython supports pythonql or not? error is coming because of  #coding: pythonql its not acceptable in jython how to do it?..

Comment: Hmm, never tested PythonQL on jython, the install procedure might need to be modified. Will check